# Break line on each tag attribute and keep them aligned in Visual Studio HTML code editor

Tags: html, visual-studio, tags, formatting, line-breaks

### If you'd like to see this implemented in the next version of VS, please vote for it [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3657691-break-line-on-each-tag-attribute-and-keep-them-ali).

---

Suppose the following horizontally lengthy `<button>` `HTML` declaration:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="save" name="action:@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]"><i class="icon-save icon-large"></i> @Localization.Save</button>
```

As you see all tag attributes are inline such that they extend a long way to right in the code editor...

Do you know of any Visual Studio option or extension that allows it to be formatted with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> like this:

```
<button type="submit"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        id="save"
        name="action:@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]">
<i class="icon-save icon-large"></i>@Localization.Save
</button>
```

I think the above format makes it easy to spot a given attribute although it'll clearly make the vertical scroll-bar a little longer. :)

I tried fiddling with Visual Studio options in `TOOLS => Options... => Text Editor => HTML` but didn't find an option to control this behavior.

Of course I can align it manually but then if I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> by mistake I lose all the custom made formatting.

If there's no such a thing available, I think this makes a great idea for a Visual Studio extension. As a plus it could even alphabetically order the attributes. :)

---

Doing a little bit more Googling I found that the `XAML` editor in Visual Studio has what I'd like to have in the HTML editor:

[Position each attribute on a separate line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763100.aspx)

[image]

---

I asked this same question at the Visual Studio Extensibility forum:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/0d97c205-9f29-4ba7-9d0b-253413077dce/

---

### If you'd like to see this implemented in the next version of VS, please vote for it [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3657691-break-line-on-each-tag-attribute-and-keep-them-ali).

Comment: Find/Replace < with /n< + don't forget to click Use Regular Expressions

Comment: Links to User Voice no longer valid. This has solicited opinions on tools to use....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you feel brave, you can write an editor extension that does this for you. Take a look at the align extension that Noah wrote a while ago for ideas: https://github.com/NoahRic/AlignAssignments

Comment: Yeah... I'm right now reading this one: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/188df4b2-7138-4070-8fcc-271abe645293/ where the guy wants to remove blank lines from HTML files.

Comment: Hey Ameen... when I have more free time I'll go a little deeper on this. In the meantime, please vote for it to make it in the next VS version: [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3657691-break-line-on-each-tag-attribute-and-keep-them-ali "merely an example")

Answer (score 7):

Well, I found a trick at the ASP.NET Forums:

[Positioning each attribute on a separate line](http://forums.asp.net/t/1376524.aspx/1)

It's not like the `XAML` feature described in my question but it works.

> In Options/Text Editor/HTML/Format you can check "Wrap tags when
>   exceeding specific length" and set the length to 1. That will cause
>   the formatter to wrap like crazy.

---

Another option is:

1. Go to `TOOLS => Options... => Text Editor => XML => Formatting` => Align attributes each on a separate line.
2. Close the .cshtml file. Right click it in Solution Explorer and select Open With... then select XML (text) Editor. Select all content and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

   *** This second option is tedious! :(

Answer (score 1):

This has been implemented in the new HTML editor in Visual Studio 2013 Preview, which has been released.  This is a feature of the new editor only, which works for html and cshtml files, but not for aspx/ascx files.
If you hit [return] after each value, the attributes will stack up under the first attribute definition.  Format Document will not undo these changes anymore.

Comment: Nice to know about this... this is a progress indeed. I downloaded and installed VS 2013 Preview but didn't have time to play with it yet. Will take a look... It would be great if there was an option in VS `Tools => Options...` to make this (neatly stacked attributes) the default behavior when pressing `Ctrl+K` then `Ctrl+F` just like XAML formatting spacing as shown in the question's screenshot. This way one wouldn't need to the formatting manually.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the html to the xml editor let it format it for you, then save it back to the html file