# Format html code in Visual Studio Code such that attributes are on separate lines?

Tags: html, formatting, visual-studio-code

There seems to be a lack of formatting settings for vscode.
I want to be able to format html such that my html shows up as:

```
<div attrib1=value1
     attrib2=value2
     attrib3=value3>
  Content
</div>
```

This is one functionality that I'd really love to have!

Comment: This would be really great, i had created an issue within github, maybe it gets considered. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2204

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate (I hate to say it...) of [this question,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791592/break-line-on-each-tag-attribute-and-keep-them-aligned-in-visual-studio-html-cod) and possibly a little off-topic in the way it is written. Please correct me if I'm wrong ;)

Comment: This one is about Visual Studio Code, the other one Visual Studio. Different editors, different settings, same vendor.

Comment: Emphasis on **"Content" having it's own line without the ">" character in front**.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

VSCode added a way to do this now.
You can edit your `settings.json` (ctrl+shift+p) and then add the following for the desired effect:

```
"html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-aligned"
```

--or--

```
"html.format.wrapAttributes": "force"
```

force-aligned will also add indents to align it with the attribute on the line where tag was opened.

Visit [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2204) for more details or updates.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a miss (for me). They should have added a wrap threshold. There are times your template is nice and short, so the attributes can remain in one line.

Comment: `force-expand-multiline` is the best option for me right now

Comment: but when I save the file it converts in one line

Answer (score 6):

My extended html was being limited by the "Prettier: Print width" setting, I thought I'd put a random value as 0, but then all the tags start breaking the attributes. So he put 10,000. This solved my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are differnt "formatter" extensions, but one I found does a decent job of this exact formatting that you are looking for.
It's called "**vscode-tidyhtml**".

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=anweber.vscode-tidyhtml

1. Click on the Extensions icon on the left hand side
2. Search for and install "vscode-tidyhtml", reload Visual Studio Code
3. Hit the "F1" key, and then type "TidyHtml", hit enter

It should format HTML so that attributes are on different lines. I am not sure if it works well for other file types.

Comment: It removes **AngularJs** directives.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but I came here searching for an answer too. As @adi518 mentioned, the vscode automatic formatting for this might not be a great idea.

So, to do it where you'd like it, this extension might help:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dannyconnell.split-html-attributes

Comment: The problem with this, is that as soon as you save the file, VSCode puts the attributes right back in line again.

Answer (score 1):

You should open the settings.json file (shift+cmd+p for mac) and click on Open Preference: Open Settings (JSON)

add the following line at the beginning of the JSON file:

```
"html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-aligned",
```

In case formatting still does not work (this is a different issue), search for HTML and add the following lines

```
"[html]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
```

Close and Open vscode then format by using (option+Shift+F)

Answer (score 0):

Via VSCode, install Extension:
Prettier - Code formatter v9.16.0

Control + Shift + P , to open 'Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)'

```
"[html]": {
        // "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features",
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
```

Then go back to your HTML(.ts) document
Shift + Alt + F, to format document

Comment: Does the default prettier formatting work like OP is looking for?

Comment: For me, it did not work after I install extension 'Prettier', it could be that I have more than 1 extension installed

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling visual studio code solved the problem for me