# How to format HTML attributes to be on multiple lines?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, formatting

I have my html code in the following format:

```
<a href="#step-1" id="accountInfoTab" role="tab" aria-controls="accountInfo"
  :aria-expanded="activeSection == 'step-1' ? 'true': 'false'" @click="triggerActiveSection('step-1')">
  <span class="step-no hidden-sm hidden-xs"
    v-html="$options.filters.i18n('registration-form-label-tab-step-1')"></span>
  <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">{{ "registration-form-label-tab-account-info" | i18n }}</span>
</a>
```

I want to reformat my code to the following format:

```
<a
  href="#step-1"
  id="accountInfoTab"
  role="tab"
  aria-controls="accountInfo"
  :aria-expanded="activeSection == 'step-1' ? 'true': 'false'"
  @click="triggerActiveSection('step-1')">
  <span class="step-no hidden-sm hidden-xs" v-html="$options.filters.i18n('registration-form-label-tab-step-1')"></span>
  <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">{{ "registration-form-label-tab-account-info" | i18n }}</span>
</a>
```

Is there a keyboard shortcut or any other way to do it (except manually spacing the code since it is going to take ages) in VScode or any other tools out there?

Answer (score 3):

You can go to `extensions` in the editor and search for `prettier` then install it. Then you don't need to setting up anything just go to your code and press `shift + i` or `shift+alt+f` . Cheers! your code is nicely formatted.

https://prettier.io/

Comment: works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Check the solution here (should be as simple as editing your settings.json): [Format html code in Visual Studio Code such that attributes are on separate lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33560205/format-html-code-in-visual-studio-code-such-that-attributes-are-on-separate-line)

Comment: This is not the same, it keeps the first attribute on the same line as the tag.