# In VSCode, how do I make an html element look like a list with a shortcut?

Tags: html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lG8x.png)

I am watching a video and I saw an element starting to look like a list after the presenter used a shortcut. How can I do the same?

Comment: Do you mean the code formatting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format html code in Visual Studio Code such that attributes are on separate lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33560205/format-html-code-in-visual-studio-code-such-that-attributes-are-on-separate-line)